# How can i force browser to logout user whenever clearing the browser cache in angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular

When someone's clear their **browser cache** by hitting **ctrl + shift + del** the user should also logout from the website in **angular 7**?

Comment: Is that a question or a statement?

Comment: apologies it's a question.

Comment: i think this might be [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/620548) what reason do you have to do such a thing?

Comment: @UtsavUpadhyay the best answer to your question is read this : https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/10/angular-8-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial

Comment: all of your solotuions aren't working but thank you for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

You could periodically check to see whether any cookies still exist, these will generally be deleted when users clear their browser cache.

```
document.cookie = 'present=true';

var interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (!document.cookie || document.cookie.indexOf('present') === -1) {
        // call your logout function here
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 10000);
```

Comment: or in angular you could  configure a  error interceptor to logout when 401 response from a api call or use a combination of guards , interceptors and server response